# .NET Core Web API posting formdata and getting 400 error

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I believe the issue is with the null values. I have tested payloads that contained values such as

```
{
 name: 'My Name', 
 householdSize: '3'
}
```

and the server would get the request. However, I want to still allow users to not input any data, however, when this occurs, the server is never hit (I have a breakpoint to test).

I am using a js frontend with a .NET Core Web API.

I have a payload that looks like

```
{
 name: null, 
 householdSize: null
}
```

My view model is as such

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public EHouseholdSize HouseholdSize { get; set; }

    public enum EHouseholdSize
    {
        One = 1,
        Two,
        Three,
        Four,
        FivePlus
    }
}
```

My controller is as such

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Add([FromBody]QuestionnaireViewModel viewModel)
{
    if(!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest();
    }

    // Do stuff        

    return Ok();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use API Controller (has [ApiController] attribute), the action parameters will be automaticaly validated and you don' t need if ( !ModelState.IsValid ) since it will never be hitted if model state is invalid. Api controller will return BadRequest before it. So remove the [Required] attribute from your ViewModel properties or make them not null

Another thing is if your project has enabled nullable (mostly net 6 projects)

```
  <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
```

you will need to make a property Name nullable too

```
 public string? Name { get; set; }
```

Otherwise you will get a BadRequest "The Name field is required.", even if you remove [Required] attribute.

Comment: So can I always assume that a 400 error from the controller action means something in my payload is not correct?

Comment: @SomeDev , yes your input parameters are not valid but  controller always runs automatic validation check.

Comment: So ok the frontend, if my response is 400, I guess I will assume the form data is incorrect then. Thank you.

Comment: @SomeDev , it is not about form data, it is model that you are sending using ajax  is not valid according to your data attributes

Comment: But then how does the server validate then? I can't just allow the user to input anything they want? There has to be some sort of server side validation? Say the user inputs something, but the Name has to be more than 1 character...how would I validate this?

Comment: @SomeDev You were told already . Just remove required attributes and do what you want. What makes sense to put restrictions if you don't want them?

Comment: So my ViewModel essentially does all the validation is what you are saying? This is my first time creating a Web API and I've used the traditional .NET MVC type apps...so if I understand correctly, as long as my action is hit successfully (by testing via breakpoint), I can assume my viewmodel(meaning formdata) is valid?

Comment: @SomeDev Yes, you are right. But I see you posted the brilliant answer where you turned off validation of all actions of all controllers. I don't think that it is a good idea. You need just remove requiered attribute from the properties where you don't need it instead of turning off any validation.

Comment: yes you are right - I notice this after

Answer (score 1):

Your `ModelState` is not valid when sending `null` values because both of the property of your view model has `[Required]` attribute. Sending `{"name": null, "houseHoldSize": null}` is equivalent to `` or `{}`.
Therefore, not fulfilling the requirements and makes the model state invalid. That's why it's never pass your if block.

So if you want to allow posting null or empty values, you need to remove the `[Required]` attribute from your ViewModel properties.

Comment: I see. However, let's say I post invalid data. For example, say I post an enum of value 7 which doesn't exist and is an invalid argument. Would the server still get the request? And no, actually the 400 isn't even coming from the API. The request itself doesn't even hit the API at all.

Comment: I think it will. Unless you specify `Data Annotations` for that maybe.

Comment: What do you think? Who sends the 400 response then if the request doesn't hit the API? As mentioned in the other answers, the `[ApiController]` attribute can do some works automagically.